# Post Bad Request rest api in python

Tags: python, api, rest, endpoint

I am attempting to post some data through REST API in Python.

data.json

```
    {
      "LastModifiedAt": "2020-12-21T20:19:45.335Z",
       ...
       ...
    }
```

I am using following code to POST the data.

```
with open('data.json') as fh:
    data = json.load(fh)
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'X-API-Key':'ABC=='
}
response = requests.post('https://myurl.net/api/v1/resource/int_key/endpoint', headers=headers,data=data)
```

I always get following as response `status_code = 400`

```
{
    "ModelState": {
        "line": [
            "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: L. Path '', line 0, position 0."
        ]
    }, 
    "Message": "The request is invalid."
}
```

How do I debug this? My URL is correct according to API documentation. Why does it return "Bad Request" status code?

Comment: I bet there is something wrong with the header and API connection, not with python at all.

Comment: Do you have access to the deserializing code on the backend. Can you post your entire JSON? It is almost certainly one of the attributes being incorrectly formatted. Passing dates is especially tricky if the deserializer is not setup to recognize the format. Also, try sending it with Postman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced `data` with `json` and it worked.

`response = requests.post('https://myurl.net/api/v1/resource/int_key/endpoint', headers=headers,`**json**`=data)`

I used Postman as suggested by AndroidDev to debug this.